# React Native : function component or class component approach?

Tags: react-native

I started learning React Native some days ago, having never worked with it or even React.js before, and according to [React Native Dev website](https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started#function-components-and-class-components), there seems to be two different approaches when it comes to React Native code writing. The issue is, as I learn reading several docs and watching tutorials, it gets a bit confusing to me at times, having to figure out which approach is used.

Is one of these approaches more recent than the other ?

Is there one I should favour at the expense of the other ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the functional component approach is "newer" since there has been a lot of emphasis on using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) as of late.

Personally, the ability to use hooks is a huge plus for me so I always look to use functional components if I can. I also find that I can do the same thing in a lot less code when I use functional components + hooks.